# Usage of RXJava map in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Why is this complaining about a miss-type? `map` supposed to transfor the value of an observable to another, but it's expecting me to return an observable from the map

```
override fun fetchExercises(): Observable<List<Exercise>> {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference("exercises")
        .observeSingleEvent()
        .map { snapshot: DataSnapshot? -> object: List<Exercise>
            // Error here
            return listOf<Exercise>()
        }
    }

fun DatabaseReference.observeSingleEvent(): Observable<DataSnapshot> {
    return Observable.create(object : Observable.OnSubscribe<DataSnapshot> {
        override fun call(subscriber: Subscriber<in DataSnapshot>) {

            val valueEventListener = object: ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                    subscriber.onNext(snapshot)
                    subscriber.onCompleted()
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
                    subscriber.onError(FirebaseDatabaseThrowable(error))
                }
            }

            addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of your code

```
.map { snapshot: DataSnapshot? -> object: List<Exercise>
```

says that the type of the `snapshot` parameter that this lambda receives is `DataSnapshot? -> object: List<Exercise>` (which actually isn't a valid function type, that would be `DataSnapshot? -> List<Exercise>`).

I believe what you actually wanted to do is the following, a `snapshot` parameter that just has the type `DataSnapshot`:

```
.map { snapshot: DataSnapshot? ->
    listOf<Exercise>()
}
```

The return type of the lambda doesn't have to be specified here, it will just be inferred. You also don't need to use the `return` keyword in a lambda, because the last expression in it is what's returned.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks. Need to get Swift out of my head while writing Kotlin :)

Answer (score 6):

@zsmb13 has pointed out the correct answer right there. Here, I would like to comment on some mistake made in your lambda expression.

```
.map { snapshot: DataSnapshot? -> object: List<Exercise>
        // Error here
        return listOf<Exercise>()
}
```

`object: List<Exercise>` here is not a valid syntax since the body goes after an `->` sign inside the lambda expression. We do not specify the return type inside the body.

Also, the `return` here means to return from `fetchExercises()` as described in [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions):

> A return statement without a label always returns from the function declared with the fun keyword. This means that a return inside a lambda expression will return from the enclosing function, whereas a return inside an anonymous function will return from the anonymous function itself.

As what @zsmb13 said, `return` is not needed in most of the case. If you really want it(for flow control), you can use [qualified returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

```
//This is answer from @zsmb13
.map { snapshot: DataSnapshot? ->
    return@map listOf<Exercise>()
}
```